# Is there anyone tried xpath for radio button created using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, xpath

I have below snippet of html code which is created using reactjs and could you please help me out finding xpath for the same? When I try with chromepath it is throwing this error "This is a pseudo element and selectors can't be generated for pseudo element".

Snippet:

[image]

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried so far. Also share the HTML in the question rather than in an image.

Comment: Hi @SariqShaikh, below is the html snippet and xpath tried :
<div data-testid="pcr-wrapper" class="pretty p-default d-form__field d-form__field--default p-round">
<input id="BDM" type="radio" data-testid="pcr-input" value="BDM" checked="">
<div class="state" data-testid="pcr-state">
<label for="BDM">
::before
<b>Data Engineering products</b>
::after
</label>
</div>
</div>

xpath tried : //div[@class='state']/input[@value='Data Engineering products']